# Why this ptrace error?

Tags: c, linux, ptrace

I'm just testing read and write memory via `ptrace()` call, but when I run the code shown below, I got an error like this.

```
Processkey() : 0x80481240
readmem pid 3950
Original opcode : 0x4641682b
writemem pid 3950
readmem pid 3950
PEEKDATA error: No such file or directory
```

As you can see, `readmem()` works fine, but afterwards, `readmem()` prints an error.

```
long readmem(int pid, unsigned long addr)
{
    long ret=0;
    printf("readmem pid %d\n", pid);
    ret = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, pid, (void *)(addr), 0);
    if(ret<0)
    {
        error("PEEKDATA error");
    }
    return ret;
}

void writemem(int pid, unsigned long addr, long data)
{
    long ret=0;
    printf("writemem pid %d\n", pid);
    ret = ptrace(PTRACE_POKEDATA, pid, (void *)addr, (void *)data);
    if(ret<0)
    {
        error("POKEDATA error");
    }
}

void detach(int pid)
{
    long ret=0;
    ret = ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
    if(ret<0)
    {
        error("detach() error");
    }
}

void attach(int pid)
{
    long ret=0;
    ret = ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
    if(ret<0)
    {
        error("ptrace() error");
    }

    ret = waitpid(pid, NULL, WUNTRACED);
    if(ret<0)
    {
        error("waitpid ()");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    long ret = 0;
    pid_t pid = 0;
    REGS *regs;
    unsigned long processkey_addr = 0;
    int stat_value = 0;
    long op = 0;

    pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    processkey_addr = 0x80481240;
    printf("Processkey() : 0x%lx\n", processkey_addr);

    attach(pid);
    op = readmem(pid, processkey_addr);
    printf("Original opcode : 0x%lx\n", op);
    writemem(pid, processkey_addr, 0x41424344);
    printf("Changed opcode : 0x%lx\n", readmem(pid, processkey_addr));
    detach(pid);
}
```

But — and this made me crazy — when I tested code without the functions (just wrote the code inline in `main()`), this whole code worked fine!

Does anyone know why this happens...?

Comment: Your trace code in `readmem()` should probably print the address from which it is reading too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a bit odd, but there's at least one actual error in your code. From the manual page:

> On error, all requests return -1, and errno is set appropriately. Since the value returned by a successful PTRACE_PEEK* request may be -1, the caller must check errno after such requests to determine whether or not an error occurred.

It seems your code does not check `errno`, it just assumes an error occured if the return value is -1.